# Associate result of operation to the hashmap value

Tags: clojure, hashmap

I have 2 maps:

```
(def look {"directions" :look
       "look" :look
       "examine room" :look
       })

(def quit {"exit game" :quit
       "quit game" :quit
       "exit" :quit
       "quit" :quit
       })
```

which are merged into one map by:

```
(defn actions [] (merge look quit))
```

and then I try to associate its result (which is a hash-map) into value of another map:

```
(assoc {} :1 actions)
```

but instead of expected result which should be:

```
{1: {"directions" :look, "look" :look ...
```

I receive

```
{:1 #object[fun_pro.core$actions 0x20a8027b "fun_pro.core$actions@20a8027b"]}
```

which is, as I understand reference to the action object.

What should I do to receive expected result? I tried also use of unquote-splicing but I'm not advanced enough to use macros yet and couldn't make it works.

EDIT1:

OK, It seem I found the solution. Instead of using `(defn actions...)` I should use `(def actions...)`.

EDIT2:

To clarify why I use such a structure.

As I said in comment below,  I will use this maps to compare it with the answer provided by user to find which command to use. For example if user type "show me directions", it will trigger function to display directions based on keyword "directions". The same result will be if user will ask "I look around the room" or "I examine room to find road", based on keywords "look" and "examine room".

It will be done by first splitting user input into set of strings and find if there is common word with keys from my map (turned into set). So input `"show me directions"` will be processed into set  `#{"show" "me" "directions"}`. Then I will use `clojure.set/intersection` to find if there is common element with set of map keywords and trigger function accordingly to result (I have already coded algorithm for that).

Of course I'm open for any suggestions if there is better solution for it.

Comment: Your map is backwards.  Use symbols as keys, not as values.  Depending on what you are trying to do, a map may not even be the right choice.

Comment: @jmargolisvt What? Why would you say that his map is backwards just because it maps strings to keywords? A quick examination of his data makes it very clear what he's trying to do.

Comment: @MarcinKruglik Since you've found the solution, could you post it as an answer instead of as an edit to the question?

Comment: @jmargolisvt I will use this maps to compare it with the answer provided by user to find which command to use. For example if user type "show me directions", it will trigger function to display directions based on keyword "directions". The same result will be if user will ask "I look around the room" or "I examine room to find road", based on keywords "look" and "examine room". That's why I use String. I try to implement code provided by my lecturer in Lisp into Clojure.

Comment: @Elogent, when I say what he's trying to do, I don't mean his immediate goal of merging them.  I mean that as he continues to add to the list of actions, having them keyed with strings won't be very useful.  Nor will it be ideal to keep adding a :quit symbol to each one.  I would use a nested map and make a vector out of the strings.  This way @MarcinKruglik, you can display your list of actions simply: `(-> :list-of-actions :action-name)`.

Comment: @jmargolisvt The fact that typing the same keyword repeatedly would be inconvenient can be remedied by something like `(into {} (for [s ["directions" "look" "examine room"]] [s :look]))`, but that's not important. What's important is that he's *not* trying to go from an action (represented by a keyword) to a list of user inputs (represented by strings). He's trying to go the *other* way, which is why mapping from keywords to sequences of strings in this case would be pointless.

Comment: @Elogent @jmargolisvt I think your argument is pointless as I can easily change string into keyword and us it as keys in map. The only problem is I can't create something like `:exit game` (with space). I have to think yet how to implement check if phrase contains 2 words. Again I have the code provided to me by my lecturer in Racket and I try to "translate" it into Clojure as I decided to learn Clojure instead of Lisp as part of functional programming module. Both languages are dialects of Lisp but they are significant different. Personally I think Clojure is more user friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, It seem I found the solution on my own. Instead of using `(defn actions...)` I should use `(def actions...)`.

This results of desired output.